# Bigquery querying by time of event

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I use standard SQL for Bigquery. I need to find all events that happened in the morning, afternoon or evening. I can do something like this

```
WHERE TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event.timestamp_micros) BETWEEN '2017-04-01 12:00:00' AND '2017-06-01 16:00:00'
```

But I need only time without date. Is there some way to query only by time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in BigQuery Standard SQL you can use

```
EXTRACT(HOUR FROM TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event.timestamp_micros))
```

Below is usage example

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  CASE 
    WHEN hr >= 4 AND hr < 12 THEN 'morning' 
    WHEN hr >= 12 AND hr < 15 THEN 'afternoon'
    WHEN hr >= 15 AND hr < 17 THEN 'late_afternoon'
    WHEN hr >= 17 AND hr < 19 THEN 'evening'
    WHEN hr >= 19 AND hr < 21 THEN 'late_evening'
    ELSE 'night' 
  END AS day_part
FROM `dataset.yourtable`, 
UNNEST([EXTRACT(HOUR FROM TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event.timestamp_micros))]) AS hr
```

Comment: Great. Thank you

Comment: what if I need to change the UNNEST fucntion to 'TIME_TRUNC(TIME(Request_Timestamp), SECOND) AS Time' and getting error 'Table-valued function not found: TIME_TRUNC at [26:1]'

Comment: @swm - it is not possible to answer in comments - please feel free to post new question with all relevant details and we will be happy to help

Comment: Getting an error message 'Unrecognized name:event".

Answer (score 1):

There are two fundamentally different approaches.  One is to convert the value to a timestamp and then work with the timestamp -- say by formatting the value as an hour.

Another is to just work with the microseconds.  You can do what you want with division and modulus arithmetic.  So, to calculate the hour of the day:

```
where mod(cast(event.timestamp_micros / (1000000 * 60 * 60) as int64), 24) between 12 and 13
```

Note that this gets times from 12:00:00 and 13:59.59.999999.

Comment: I get Error: No matching signature for function MOD for argument types: FLOAT64, INT64. Supported signatures: MOD(INT64, INT64)

Answer (score 1):

BigQuery has a [`TIME` type](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#time-type) that you can use. For example,

```
SELECT
  COUNTIF(time BETWEEN '04:00:00' AND '12:00:00') AS morning_events,
  COUNTIF(time BETWEEN '12:00:00' AND '20:00:00') AS evening_events,
  COUNTIF(time < '04:00:00' OR time > '20:00:00') AS night_events
FROM (
  SELECT
    EXTRACT(TIME FROM TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event.timestamp_micros)) AS time
  FROM YourTable
);
```

Comment: what if i just wanna show in table the result (monrning etc) instead of count?